# can I embed asterisk wildcard * in python selenium switch_to.frame()

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I've encountered with a problem.
when I need to switch to iframe, the id & name of the iframe varies all the time, from iframe1~iframe9, I am always getting the 'NoSuchFrameException',so how can I embed an asterisk wildcard into the iframe's name, just like :

driver.switch_to.frame('iframe*')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only ever one iframe, or they're always in the same order, you can use the index:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
```

If it's more complicated, rather than directly putting the name in the `switch_to.frame` call, you can search for the frame first, then pass it as a variable; that will let you search by anything, or even loop through all the iframes and check for the one you want in python code.

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xxx(...)
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, the first one is very good for me. Because the target iframe is the 2nd iframe in the source html, so I use driver.switch_to.frame(1), it works nicely.